# ¿como cerrar modal en boostrap5 con js?

Tags: javascript

como podria cerrar un modal de boostrap5 desde un js externo, intente con la funcion hide(), pero no mefunciono agradeceria su respuesta.

1. en la primera imagen muestro el modal en html.
2. en la segunda imagen muestro el llamado del modal en js.
3. y en la tercera imagen, se ve como intento cerrarla con hide(), como dice boostrap pero no sirve.

si alguien podria decirme como cerrar un modal de boostrap 5 se los agradeceria.

perdon por la mala publicacion, es la primera que hago.

[image: mi modal en html]

[image: llamo el modal en mi codigo js]

[image: intento cerrar mi modal con modal.hide() como dice boostrap pero no funciona]

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solución**

Para que puedas acceder a los métodos de los modales debes primero crear la instancia:

```
//Creación de la instancia 
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'));
//Ocultar modal
myModal.hide();
```

**Documentación**:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#passing-options